# Delete discord invites if someone post it in a channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want that the bot remove invites from channel if someone send one in all channels
Im using discord.py 1.6.0 and wrote it so but nothing happens.

```py
rules = xxx
links = xxx
teamroom = xxx

# regex
DISCORD_INVITE = r'discord(?:\.com|app\.com|\.gg)[\/invite\/]?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,32})'

class Mod(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.links_allowed = (rules, teamroom, links)
        self.url_regex = DISCORD_INVITE

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if search(self.url_regex, message.content):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("You cant send invites.", delete_after=10)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Mod(bot))
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be late but try this:

```
import re
discordInviteFilter = re.compile("(...)?(?:https?://)?discord(?:(?:app)?\.com/invite|\.gg)/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?")
async def on_message(message):
    if discordInviteFilter.match(message.content):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send('no invites NOPPERS')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the link posted starts with `https://discord.gg` and delete the message if the condition is met.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
      if message.content.startswith("https://discord.gg"):
         await message.delete()
         await message.channel.send("You cannot send invites.")
```

Comment: People can still bypass this, which is why regex was involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the message has discord.gg in it I think having even if the message doesn't have HTTPS it still works with discord.gg if you add HTTPS:// then users will bypass by just using discord.gg only Hope you got your answer

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment instead of an answer.